# Haskell, differences between sum(x,y) vs sum(x,y,z)

Tags: haskell, sum

I am confused about the differences between `sum (x,y)` and `sum(x,y,z)`. The type signature of `sum` appears to be `(Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a`. What I am getting is that it takes in a foldable `t` and a typeclass of `Num a`. Sum(x,y) always outputs y and sum(x,y,z) gives an error:

```
 "Could not deduce (Foldable ((,,) Integer Integer))
        arising from a use of `sum'"
```

So why is sum(x,y) able to output something compared to sum(x,y,z)

Comment: but to answer the Haskell question, it's because pairs are defined as an [instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#line-339) of `Foldable` but triples are not. It doesn't really make a lot of sense to me (nor does the instance for pairs, which simply ignores the first element), but that's how it is.

Comment: You want to try `sum [1,2]` and `sum [1,2,3]`.

Comment: Hey Robin, yes this is specifically a haskell problem. Thank you very much for editing the tags. First time using stack overflow.

Comment: The semantics for an `n`-tuple are that of a *single* value stored in a context of `n-1` other values. Something with a `Foldable` instance has to have kind `* -> *`, which in the case of product types always means having the first `n-1` values effectively ignored. `Functor` and `Foldable` both do this consistently: `fmap (+1) ('a', 3) == ('a', 4)`, while `sum ('a', 3) == 3`. (Each `Foldable` function does little more than extract a value from its context.) For 2-tuples, the instances are for `(,) a`, not `(a, b)`; for 3-tuples, they would be for `(,,) a b` not `(a, b, c)`; etc.

Comment: @chepner That's true from a formal point of view, but how often do people actually _use_ tuples like this? (`Writer` and `Control.Comonad.Env` aside)

Comment: @bradrn That's not really relevant to the question of why `Foldable` et al. are defined the way they are.

Comment: @chepner I suppose so. It's just that it may be a bit confusing from a beginner's point of view.

Comment: Well, yes, it's confusing if you persist in thinking of a tuple as just a minor variation on a list. It's not. Maybe it would be better to have *no* `Foldable` instances for the partially-applied `(,) a` types, but ones that make use of anything *other* than the last element of the tuple simply aren't an option.

Answer (score 5):

In both Python and Haskell, `(x,y,z)` is a tuple whereas `[x,y,z]` is a list. However, whereas lists are pretty much the same in both languages, <del>tuples are different: Python tuples are similar to Python lists, whereas in Haskell, tuples are a completely different concept</del> (**EDIT:** I was wrong); in Haskell, tuples are like records without field names (e.g. `(1, "foo", 'b')` is of type `(Int, String, Char)`). Thus in Haskell you can't sum tuples in general (since you can't guarantee each 'field' is of the same type), which is basically what `Could not deduce Foldable` means. However, a `Foldable` instance in the Prelude does exist for 2-tuples! As @RobinZigmond commented however, it doesn't work the way you might expect: since it can't guarantee that both fields are of the same type, it just ignores the first element completely:

```
Prelude> sum (1,2)
2
```

Comment: "lists are pretty much the same in both languages" - I would dispute that. Haskell's lists are true "linked lists" whereas I'm pretty sure Python's "lists" are really arrays. (And therefore more efficient - Haskell lists are pretty inefficient for a lot of things you'd use lists for in Python.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond True. I meant that in both languages lists are used for the same concept (that of a list of values), whereas tuples aren't.

Comment: @bradrn Other way around, tuples are used for the same concept, lists are different, however most people use them in the same way: a homogeneous list of items.

Comment: "it doesn't work properly" it works completely properly, the way it works just isn't really what most people would expect.

Comment: There is another way in which Haskell and Python tuples are closer to each other than Haskell and Python lists are: tuples are immutable in both languages, whereas Python lists are mutable and Haskell lists are immutable.

Comment: @Elmex80s As you may have noticed from this discussion I am _not_ a Python expert. After a bit of research I've realised I'm wrong; I'll edit the mistakes out.

Comment: @Cubic I see DanielWagner has edited this in - thanks!